# Bar Button Item Issue

Tags: ios, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a Bar Button called SAVE when the program running its automatically displays the title of SAVE but while i edit the contents in that particular view, the title should be changed as EDIT is there any codings are available for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tag in your button.

```
-(IBAction) add:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag] == 0){

// set the button title as "Save"      

    }
    else{
// set the button title as "Edit"  
        Button1.tag=0;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i looked. +1.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a solution for this, and its called `editButtonItem()`.

What you need to do is add this in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.editButtonItem().action = "yourAction"
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the instance of your `UIBarButtonItem` then you can try doing the below code
I suppose you have your object with the name "objSaveButton".

`[objSaveButton setTitle:@"EDIT"];`

or  if you don't have the instance you can get the same from `UINavigationController`

if it is your left bar button item do this: 
        `[navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"EDIT"];`

and if it is your right bar button do this:

```
[navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"EDIT"];
```